Can a person with limited hand strength operate a heavy duty First Alert extinguisher?
How much hand strength is required to squeeze the trigger on a heavy duty First Alert extinguisher?

This isn't a home improvement question. It also depends almost entirely on the specific definition of "limited".

A quick search on the First Alert web site didn't provide much useful information. However, I did find a site with ADA requirements:

309.4 Operation. Operable parts shall be operable with one hand and shall not require tight grasping, pinching, or twisting of the wrist.  The force required to activate operable parts shall be 5 pounds (22.2 N) maximum.

I would expect a residential fire extinguisher, even "heavy duty", to generally be at the lower end of the range in terms of both total weight (which is an important factor) and ease of use. But beyond that, contacting First Alert is probably the way to get a definitive answer.
